# Finding if a matrix is square

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix which is constructed element by element through some iterations, and thus can be non-square. If it's not square, then I want to make it square filling with `0`. **Is there a function to determine if a matrix is square?**

I was thinking of something like this:

```
(* If determinant of matrix is possible, then fill with 0s, else do nothing. *)
If[Det[matrix]=Indeterminate,Fillwithzeros[matrix]]
```

I'm pretty sure `Det[matrix] = Indeterminate` is not a correct way to express my thoughts, so maybe you could help me out with my syntax or even suggest a better way to do it :D

Thanks!

Comment: What about `Dimensions` and some `ArrayPad`?

Comment: Compare `Equal @@ Dimensions[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]` and `Equal @@ Dimensions[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}]` :)

Comment: Hmm, gotta look into Dimensions. This seems a lot easier. Thanks, guys :D

Comment: BTW: Det[matrix]=Indeterminate is trying to set the value of Det[matrix] equal to Indeterminate not test if it is.  Testing if A equals B is written ==.  However Indeterminate is a symbol so you need === in that case.

Comment: @SaxoMikoMola and where would you like the fill the rectangle matrix?

Comment: In V10, there is/will be [`SquareMatrixQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquareMatrixQ.html)

Comment: @Ymareth, I was trying using `==` but showed an error, now I see why. Thank you.

@Öskå actually I was aiming to fill-in the missing elements if some rows didn't have the same length as the rest of the rows. `Dimensions` did the job, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are concerned about the case where you list of lists has unequal length sublists then you should first do `MatrixQ`:

```
MatrixQ[#] && MatchQ[  Dimensions[#] , {_ ..}] &@ RandomInteger[10,{3,3}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

or

```
MatrixQ[#] && Equal @@ Dimensions@# &@{{1, 2, 1}, {1, 4, 4}, {4, 5, 4}}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

### padding

```
 Normal@SparseArray[#, ConstantArray[Max@Dimensions@#,2]] &@ RandomReal[1, {4, 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would propose, but it can probably be faster:

```
filling[mat_] := If[Equal @@ Dimensions@mat, mat,
  If[Less @@ Dimensions@mat,
  Join[mat, SparseArray[{}, {1, Max@Dimensions@mat}]],
  PadRight[mat[[#]], Max@Dimensions@mat] & /@ Range@Max@Dimensions@mat]]
```

where the test on the matrix squareness¹ is not needed.

```
mat[m_, n_] := RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {m, n}]
```

**Examples:**

```
SeedRandom@10;
mat[3, 2] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  10 & 10 \\
>  9 & 7 \\
>  8 & 6 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
SeedRandom@10;
filling[mat[3, 2]] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  10 & 10 & 0 \\
>  9 & 7 & 0 \\
>  8 & 6 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
SeedRandom@2;
mat[2, 3] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  8 & 4 & 5 \\
>  4 & 7 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
SeedRandom@2;
filling[mat[2, 3]] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  8 & 4 & 5 \\
>  4 & 7 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Timings:**

```
filling[mat[10000, 9999]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.897158, Null}
> ```

```
filling[mat[9999, 10000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.651018, Null}
> ```

```
filling[mat[10000, 10000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.253314, Null}
> ```

The last being approximately equivalent to `mat[10000, 10000]; // AbsoluteTiming`

---

¹ `squareQ = Equal @@ Dimensions@# &;`

Answer (score 1):

```
pad = With[{dim = Dimensions@#}, 
           If[Equal @@ dim, #, ArrayPad[#, {{0, 0}, Abs[dim - Max@dim]}\[Transpose]]]] &;



pad @ RandomReal[1, {4, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

**Edit** this version is going to work with multidimensional matrices too :)

```
pad = With[{dim = Dimensions@#}, 
       If[Equal @@ dim, #, ArrayPad[#, {0 dim, Abs[dim - Max@dim]}\[Transpose]]]] &;

pad @ RandomReal[1, {3, 2, 3, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

Comment: Damn, I was really wondering how to use `ArrayPad`, I guess I was missing the `Abs[dim - Max@dim]` part.. :)

Comment: @Öskå Thanks :P I was looking for more compact way but I've failed :(

Comment: It's already quite compact compared to mine :P I feel stupid now for not handling `ArrayPad` :)

Comment: @Öskå now George made me stupid ;P